# Choosing an SSL certificate provider

Tags: tls, certificates

Does it make any difference which provider I get my SSL/TLS certificate from? In particular, what are the pros and cons getting an SSL certificate from Verisign vs getting one from Thawte? Which one can be used on more devices?

Comment: What about Globalsign SSLs?...

Comment: Welcome to IT Security. Please explain the security issue you are interested in. If you are only interested in device usage and compatability your question may be better answered on a different site.

Answer (score 11):

According to Verisign, it is best to buy your certificates from Verisign, because then the obtention fee goes into Verisign's pocket, and not Thawte's pocket. Understandingly, Thawte's point of view somewhat differs.

Since they both comply to the same standard ([X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)), there's no problem in using a certificate from either in any kind of device. What *could* make a CA a better choice than any other is:

- whether one CA could get its root public key included in most OS and Web browsers by default, and not the other;
- whether one CA has an easier to use issuing procedure;
- whether one CA asks for less money per certificate than the other.

In practice, Verisign and Thawte are quite on par with each other for all these criteria, so you may choose the one which has the Web site colours which please you most, or whatever. If you really must make a choice, it won't be technical, rather legal: which one offers the best financial guarantees if a mishap occurs ? See with your legal department, then.

Comment: Both Verisign (the SSL part) and Thawte are subsidiaries of Symantec.

Comment: There are potential technical (performance) differences: https://revocation-report.x509labs.com